# Access non visible query fields from listbox selection

Tags: ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2013

I've currently got a form with a listbox which displays the results of a selected field in a query. I only want this one column/field to be visible to the user, but I want to be able to access the other columns of the query based on the selected item in the listbox to perform calculations with. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample:
Base your listbox on a query i.e. like this:

```
SELECT CompanyId, CompanyName FROM t_Companies ORDER BY CompanyName;
```

In the listbox set the following properties:
Column Count: 2
Column Width: 0;10
That's it.
It will show in the list box the CompanyName. It will hide the ID because the width is 0.
But if you look at the value of the listbox in VBA it will return the ID and not the name.

Maybe also have a look at this question and my answer:
[Access 2010 - display related record in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755285/access-2010-display-related-record-in-a-form/27763136#27763136)